# Python: get DNS query from a specific, hardcoded server

Tags: python, dns, dig

How do I do `dig TXT +short o-o.myaddr.l.google.com @8.8.4.4` in Python?

(That line resolves the hostname `o-o.myaddr.l.google.com` through the DNS server `8.8.4.4`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [*`dnspython`*](https://dnspython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), which is a DNS toolkit for Python. This can be [installed via *`pip`*](https://dnspython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html).

```
pip install dnspython
```

You can then use [*`dns.resolver.Resolver`*](https://dnspython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolver-class.html#dns.resolver.Resolver) class from this module to query the DNS records.

```
>>> import dns.resolver
>>> resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
>>> resolver.nameservers = ["8.8.4.4"]
>>> answer = resolver.resolve("<Your Domain>", 'TXT') # Query TXT record.
```